# Парсинг шорткодов

Tags: регулярные-выражения, парсер

Дан текст с включенными в него тегами следующего вида:

```
[НАИМЕНОВАНИЕ_ТЕГА:описание]данные[/НАИМЕНОВАНИЕ_ТЕГА]
```

На выходе нужно получить 2 массива:

Первый:

- Ключ - наименование тега
- Значение - данные

Второй:

- Ключ - наименование тега
- Значение - описание

Вложенность тегов не допускается.

Описания может и не быть.

Обязателен закрывающий тег.

Пробую пока без описания:

```
#\[[a-zA-Z]\][a-zA-Z]\[\/\1\]#msi
```

, но не работает.

Comment: `'~\[(\w+):([^]]*)](.*?)\[/\1]~su'` - и берите значения из подмасок. `'~\[(\w+):([^]]*)]((?:(?!\[\1:).)*?)\[/\1]~su'`, наверное, не понадобится.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\[([^]]+)(?::?([^][]+)?)\](.*?)\[\/\1\]
```

---

Разбор по частям:

Ищем тег с необязательным описанием. кидаем его в первую подстроку, описание во вторую

```
\[([^]]+)(?::?([^][]+)?)\]
```

Нежадно ищем всё подряд и кидаем в третью подстроку

```
(.*?)
```

Ищем первую подстроку в скобках со слешем

```
\[\/\1\]
```

---

https://regex101.com/r/td3GTc/2